# What are the cases in which arrays decay to pointers?

Tags: c, pointers, multidimensional-array

I know only one case
 when arrays passed to a function they decay into a pointer.Can anybody elaborate all the cases in which arrays decay to pointers.

Comment: This **has** to be a dupe of something, somewhere.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII I don't think that's a duplicate, here the OP asks for a list of all cases, I don't see one over there.

Comment: This is not a duplicate of any question that I know of. Please stop voting to close unless you have a good reason. It's a legitimate and good question as-written.

Comment: @R.. You might consider casting a reopen vote.

Comment: Thanks. It wasn't yet closed at the time I commented. I've voted to reopen now.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

C 2011 6.3.2.1 3:

> Except when it is the operand of the **sizeof** operator,… or the unary **&** operator, or is a string literal used to initialize an array, an expression that has type
>   “array of *type*” is converted to an expression with type “pointer to
>   *type*” that points to the initial element of the array object and is not an lvalue.

In other words, arrays *usually* decay to pointers. The standard lists the cases when they *do not*.

One might think that arrays act as arrays when you use them with subscripts, such as `a[3]`. However, what happens here is actually:

- `a` is converted to a pointer.
- The subscript operator acts on the pointer and the subscript to produce an lvalue designating the object. (In particular, `a[3]` is evaluated as `*((a)+(3))`. That is, `a` is converted to a pointer, 3 is added to the pointer, and the ***** operator is applied.)

Note: The C 2011 text includes “the **_Alignof** operator.” This was corrected in the C 2018 version of the standard, and I have elided it from the quote above. The operand of `_Alignof` is always a type; you cannot actually apply it to an object. So it was a mistake for the C 2011 standard to include it in 6.3.2.1 3.

Comment: My favorite summary of fundamental arrays vs. pointers differences came from my old college compiler instructor; She was rather animated about it too:  "A pointer is a variable that **holds** an address; An array quite simply, **is** an address." Hard to get much simpler than that.

Comment: @WhozCraig absolutely correct, but -- an address of *what*?