# compile error : loop through each element of an array inside a c++ function

Tags: c++

I am new to C++ and, I tried to loop through each element of an array in c++ function but there is a compile time error occur. can some one explain why this happen?

here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>

int getMax(int arr[])
{
    int max = arr[0];
    for (int x: arr){
        if ( x > max ) max = x;
    }
    return max;
}


int main()
{

    int arr[] = {4,2,5,3,6,8,1};
    int max = getMax(arr);

    std::cout << max << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

---

here is the error message:

```
get_max.cpp: In function 'int getMax(int*)':
get_max.cpp:6:17: error: 'begin' was not declared in this scope
     for (int x: arr){
                 ^
get_max.cpp:6:17: note: suggested alternative:
In file included from C:/Program Files (x86)/CodeBlocks/MinGW/lib/gcc/mingw32/5.1.0/include/c++/string:51:0,
                 from C:/Program Files (x86)/CodeBlocks/MinGW/lib/gcc/mingw32/5.1.0/include/c++/bits/locale_classes.h:40,
                 from C:/Program Files (x86)/CodeBlocks/MinGW/lib/gcc/mingw32/5.1.0/include/c++/bits/ios_base.h:41,
                 from C:/Program Files (x86)/CodeBlocks/MinGW/lib/gcc/mingw32/5.1.0/include/c++/ios:42,
                 from C:/Program Files (x86)/CodeBlocks/MinGW/lib/gcc/mingw32/5.1.0/include/c++/ostream:38,
                 from C:/Program Files (x86)/CodeBlocks/MinGW/lib/gcc/mingw32/5.1.0/include/c++/iostream:39,
                 from get_max.cpp:1:
C:/Program Files (x86)/CodeBlocks/MinGW/lib/gcc/mingw32/5.1.0/include/c++/bits/range_access.h:87:5: note:   'std::begin'
     begin(_Tp (&__arr)[_Nm])
     ^
get_max.cpp:6:17: error: 'end' was not declared in this scope
     for (int x: arr){
                 ^
get_max.cpp:6:17: note: suggested alternative:
In file included from C:/Program Files (x86)/CodeBlocks/MinGW/lib/gcc/mingw32/5.1.0/include/c++/string:51:0,
                 from C:/Program Files (x86)/CodeBlocks/MinGW/lib/gcc/mingw32/5.1.0/include/c++/bits/locale_classes.h:40,
                 from C:/Program Files (x86)/CodeBlocks/MinGW/lib/gcc/mingw32/5.1.0/include/c++/bits/ios_base.h:41,
                 from C:/Program Files (x86)/CodeBlocks/MinGW/lib/gcc/mingw32/5.1.0/include/c++/ios:42,
                 from C:/Program Files (x86)/CodeBlocks/MinGW/lib/gcc/mingw32/5.1.0/include/c++/ostream:38,
                 from C:/Program Files (x86)/CodeBlocks/MinGW/lib/gcc/mingw32/5.1.0/include/c++/iostream:39,
                 from get_max.cpp:1:
C:/Program Files (x86)/CodeBlocks/MinGW/lib/gcc/mingw32/5.1.0/include/c++/bits/range_access.h:97:5: note:   'std::end'
     end(_Tp (&__arr)[_Nm])
```

Comment: Note that the error message says `int getMax(int*)`. The messages are very cryptic, but their root cause is that your function's parameter is a pointer with a funky spelling, not an array.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the cases in which arrays decay to pointers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13569070/what-are-the-cases-in-which-arrays-decay-to-pointers)

Comment: Side note: `clang` sometimes has so much nicer diagnostics: `cannot build range expression with array function parameter 'arr' since parameter with array type 'int []' is treated as pointer type 'int *'`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to pass array by reference to keep size information:

```
template <std::size_t N>
int getMax(const int (&arr)[N])
{
    int max = arr[0];
    for (int x: arr){
        if ( x > max ) max = x;
    }
    return max;
}
```

or else you have to pass size with the pointer.

```
int getMax(const int *arr, std::size_t size)
{
    assert(arr != nullptr);
    assert(size != 0);
    return *std::max_element(arr, arr + size);
}
```

using `std::vector`/`std::array` has more natural syntax.

```
int getMax(const std::vector<int>& arr)
{
    assert(!arr.empty());
#if 1
    return *std::max_element(arr.begin(), arr.end());
#else
    int max = arr[0];
    for (int x: arr){
        if ( x > max ) max = x;
    }
    return max;
#endif
}
int main()
{
    const std::vector<int> arr{4,2,5,3,6,8,1};
    const int max = getMax(arr);

    std::cout << max << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Pedantic mode: maybe handle an empty sequence?

Comment: @lubgr: `assert` already added to version which might have empty range, up to OP to use different strategy to handle it (exception, default value, terminate, ...)

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that once you pass the array to your function, it's no longer an array but rather a pointer to its first element.

When you have that pointer to the first element, you no longer have any information about the data it points to (except its type). More importantly, you don't know anything about the *end* of the "array", which is needed for the [ranged `for` loop](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for).

The simple solution is to not use C-style plain arrays, but instead use e.g. [`std::array`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array), which will then have information about its size and can be used in a range `for` loop.

There is a way to use pass the actual array (or rather a reference to it) and get the size, as explained in [the answer from Jarod42](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54304591/440558).

---

Important note: Even when you declare an argument using `[]` (as in `int arr[]`) it's not an array. The compiler will translate it as a pointer (`int* arr` in your case), as indicated by the error message.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your function is not using an array.

```
int getMax(int arr[])  // <-- arr is not an array
```

It's impossible to have an array as a parameter to a function on C++. It makes no sense, it's just part of the history of C++. It's also a good reason to use `std::vector` instead of arrays.

In reality `arr` is a pointer, you can see this in the error message

```
get_max.cpp: In function 'int getMax(int*)':
```

and the problem is that

```
for (int x: arr){
```

is not legal when `arr` is a pointer.

What you should do instead is pass the size of the array to the function. something like

```
int getMax(int* arr, size_t size)
{
    int max = arr[0];
    for (size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i ){
        if ( arr[i] > max ) max = arr[i];
    }
    return max;
}
```

Or use `std::vector` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Raw arrays are passed as pointers, one says they 'decay' to pointers when passed to functions.

```
int getMax(int arr[])
```

is equivalent to

```
int getMax(int* arr)
```

Some people use the latter syntax for single objects and the former to indicate that a function expects an array – still it is only a pointer to (more precisely: a pointer to the array's first element).

That's the problem with raw arrays – you don't have to worry about if you use [`std::array`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) (pass by const (!) reference), but you might need to make a template function from to be able to pass arrays of arbitrary length. If you need variable length arrays (or want to avoid the template), then you can use [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

With raw arrays, you need to pass array length as another parameter and then need to use a classic loop (range based loops do not work on pointers):

```
int getMax(int const arr[], size_t length)
//             ^^^^^ you do not intend to modify the array so pass as const!
{
    int max = *arr;
    ++arr;
    while(--length) // if you didn't use arr[0] before: length--
    {
        if(*arr > max)
            max = *arr;
    }
}
```

A variant to: pass a reference to array – to be able to use arbitrary length, though, you need to make a template function of:

```
template <size_t N>
int getMax(int const(&arr)[N]) // ugly syntax, I know...
                               // again: you do not intend, so pass as const
{
    /* now your code works */
}
```

It is a reference to an array of length N, similarly, you can have pointers:

```
int(*arr)[N]
```

This is the type you get if you take the address of an array:

```
int a[7];
someFunction(a);       // a decays to pointer: int* (unless reference as above used)
someOtherFunction(&a); // a is passed as pointer to array: int(*)[7]
```

By the way: You are re-inventing the wheel, as there's already [`std::max_element`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max_element), although you need to use it with iterators. Pointers, however, are totally valid iterators, too, albeit, admitted, getting the end iterator is a bit ugly with raw arrays:

```
int main()
{
    int arr[] = {4,2,5,3,6,8,1};
    int max = *std::max_element
    (
        arr, // decays to pointer
        sizeof(arr)                     /   sizeof(*arr)
        // arr has not yet decayed          ... so you need to devide
        // to pointer so sizeof is          by size of first element
        // OK; but it is size in            to get the number of elements
        // bytes(!)...
    );
    // ...
```

Finally one last issue: you never check if the array length actually is > 0; if not, you access your array out of bounds (undefined behaviour!):

```
int max = arr[0]; // (!)
```

You can avoid this easily:

```
int max = std::numeric_limits<int>::min();
```

Only drawback: you cannot distinguish empty array from arrays containing only minimum int value. Admitted, one would not pass empty array anyway, but with std::vector, chances usually are greater. But in the end, you are on the safe side for virtually no cost – well, (usually) once taking the other branch and one additional assignment for the first element...).